# In selenium, how do I access the second image element with the same class name, without using XPath?

Tags: c#, image, selenium, testing, xpath

I am making some reusable methods that locate image elements within a page. I cannot locate by XPath as the XPath will be different on each one of the pages. Preferably, I would like to be able to access them by src but not sure if this is possible. C#. The code below shows two image elements. I am trying to access the second.

```
<span id="tube">        <img class="mode-icon" title="Train: Tube" height="42" alt="Tube" src="/images/Tube.png">  </span>

<span id="Overground">  <img class="mode-icon" title="Train: Overground" height="42" alt="Overground" src="/images/Overground.png"> </span>
```

Comment: Show `HTML` example of elements you want to match.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include them.

Comment: You can get the collection of elements by class name with `IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("mode-icon"));`  Once you have that collection you can use a foreach to evaluate each element in the collection to find the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should differentiate **absolute** `XPath` (fixed, e.g. `html/div/div/.../div/img`) and **relative** `XPath` (flexible, e.g. `//div/img[@id="some_img_id"]`). Good relative `XPath` could match required element on several pages

If you want to match target `img` with `src` attribute value, then you can use following `XPath`:

```
string imgSrc = "/images/Overground.png";
string imgXpath = String.Format("//img[@src = {0}]", imgSrc);
```

Same `XPath` expression you can use for any value of `imgSrc`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access using `src` attribute then

Using CSSSelector  -

`img[src='/images/Overground.png']`

using XPath

`//img[@src='/images/Overground.png']`

If it is fix that you have only 2 image tag in you page then you can use indexing as well -

`//span[2]/img`